# Overidding product saveAction() - reindex issues

Tags: module, reindex, save, magento1.9.2.3

I have created a custom module in which I'm overriding the standard core product **saveAction()** function (located in **app/code/core/Mage/Adminihtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php**).

Even if the custom function is an exact copy of the original one, after saving product, Magento shows "One or more of the Indexes are not up to date" message.

Is there some way I could fix this?

Comment: Please mention magento version or tags in add magento version.

Comment: added the version in question tags